# Jenkins connection of slaves to master

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am currently looking to connect my jenkins slaves to master. I am able to ssh into them via command line but while setting it up in Jenkins it says Authentication failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first the account used by your Jenkins manager/master when running (and trying to connect to the agents through SSH)

For instance, on Windows, Your Jenkins manager might be using a system account.
Or on Linux, root.

In both cases, that would mean the SSH settings accessed successfully with your regular account would *not* be available through that special runtime account.